# No route from location ... to location ... Error: No solution found by Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

Why does this warning box appear when I click the Solve button in Network Analyst toolbar?

```
No route from location "Graphic Pick 46" to location "Graphic Pick 61".
Error: No solution found.
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the snap to network option.

[image: snap to network]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Network_Analyst_options/004700000044000000/